# An adjective for concern meaning that the concern is relevant/right/correct

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

> Many people are concerned about the pollution problem in the city. The
> concern is ——————— because over the last year the city has been on
> unhealthy level for 200 days.

What adjective to use in the above context. I have thought about *relevant*, *correct*, *right*. But I think I have seen a more idiomatic word as an adjective for *concern* in such context.

Comment: I think your description is way too generic to have a single right answer ('appropriate', 'reasonable', 'correct', 'genuine', 'well-founded', 'justifiable' all seem good candidates). Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

> [justified](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/justified): having or shown to have a just, right, or reasonable
> basis

> [warranted](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/warranted):  If something is warranted, there is a good reason for
> it and it can be accepted

Answer (score 0):

A crisp adjective for this is **legit**.

Per *The Free Dictionary*, it means:

> Real; actual.

*Chronic lateness is a legit problem you are going to have to address with your staff.*

[legit](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/legit)

Comment: Also known as 'legitimate' to those who don't mind pronouncing two more syllables (and have another idea of what constitutes 'hip' verbiage? :)

Comment: The OP's example seems written in a formal style, which doesn't fit with "legit".

Comment: @Joachim Legitimate can be proposed as an answer.

Comment: For me, if I understand the nuance requested by the OP, the best word is *valid*.